# Array with generic index type

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, stl

Is there any data structure in C++11/STL/Boost which represents an array with a generic index type or do I have to implement such a type on my own?

I.e. I would like to do something like this:

```
std::set<std::string>> to_lookup, to_lookup2;
int i = 10, j = 13;

// initialization of to_lookup

// count is of the container type/data structure I am looking for
count[to_lookup] = i;
count[to_lookup2] = j;
```

I know the `std::map` and `std::unordered_map` containers from the STL but those do not match my requirements. It is critical for me that insert and look up can be done in O(1).

Comment: What is wrong with `std::unordered_map`?

Comment: what exactly do you want to achieve? are you suggesting using the `std::set` as the index in the `count` array?

Comment: What would the semantics of `count[to_lookup] = i` be?

Comment: `unordered_map` is O(1) *on average* for those operations. If that's not good enough, then I'm fairly sure you're asking for the impossible.

Comment: @Mankarse `count[to_lookup]` would represent the element of `count` on position `to_lookup`, just as with an integer array `count[3]`. So `count[to_lookup] = i` would assign `i` to this position.

@OliCharlesworth
@MikeSeymour
`unordered_map` was the best approach I found but I would be interested in a data structure which guarantees that insert/look up are in O(1). If that's not possible I of course have to use `unordered_map`. But an explanation would be nice why this is impossible.

Comment: If an injective function `f: I -> A` can be computed analytically, you can use `I` as the index domain, with `f` mapping to an address domain `A` in O(1). If `f` is surjective, you can use hashing. If the function cannot be computed by a formula, you need a look-up table.

Comment: There are excellent books on data structures...

Comment: Theoretically, you could compute a 32 bit hash and then create an array with four dimensions and using the bytes in your hash as indexes. However, this would force you to allocate 4 GB of memory if you're just storying one byte each.

Comment: As an addition to my previous comment, you could simply use the actual hash as an index, skipping multiple dimensions, but in the end you've got the same problem: lots of memory wasted (since behind the scenes it would be the same thing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is basically almost impossible to become significantly faster if you're using `std::unordered_map` already simply due to the fact that there's always some overhead based on the number of elements (so you can't get a perfect *O(1)* (unless you're able to reference all possible keys as indexes in an array)).

However, if you still think that a `std::unordered_map` is too slow simply due to the sheer amount of entries, try adding another layer reducing the number of elements in a map.

In your example, using `std::string` as keys(?), you could just use the very first character (untested but should work):

```
std::vector<std::unordered_map<const std::string, myWhateverType> > container(256);

// To access an element, this just adds one more layer:
container[key[0]][key] = value;
```

Iterating over all elements becomes a bit more complicated though. However, this essentially reduces the number of elements in your `std::unordered_map` to 1/255 (depending on the actual distribution of key values of course; if all keys start with something such as `key`, then you won't gain anything other than a small overhead).

Will it improve performance? This really depends on the number of entries and your keys.